# BeautifulSoup Doesn't Pull all Elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape information from http://www.emoryhealthcare.org/locations/offices/advanced-digestive-care-1.html .

I would like to scrape the Specialties that appear in the lower third of the page, namely "Gastroenterology" and "Internal Medicine".  When I inspect the element, I see that it is a `li` of `<div class="module bordered specialist">` yet when I attempt to loop through the soup and print the each found item, different results than expected are returned.

```
<div class="module bordered specialist">
<ul>
<li>Cardiac Care</li>
<li>Transplantation</li>
<li>Cancer Care (Oncology)</li>
<li>Diagnostic Radiology</li>
<li>Neurosciences</li>
<li>Mental Health Services</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

When I open the website in a browser, I see the above values flash prior to the contents switching to the expected results.  Is there a way for me to improve the likelihood that I am able to scrape the items that I intend to?

Comment: It sounds like the page has javascript that alters the content after it loads.

Comment: You could use `selenium` and wait a few seconds (that's how long it seems to take to change)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use selenium to wait a few seconds, then parse like you were doing before. That seemed to do the trick.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chromedriver = "/Users/Rafael/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('http://www.emoryhealthcare.org/locations/offices/advanced-digestive-care-1.html')
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
results = soup.find_all("div", { "class" : "module bordered specialist" })
print(results[0].text) #prints GastroenterologyInternal Medicine
```

Comment: Ah, OK, so selenium and a `time.sleep` allows the page to finish loading prior to parsing?

Comment: Yeah that's the idea, there are more elegant ways to do it by waiting for a specific element to load, but this site seems to be pretty consistent that it only took a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

You don't need selenium, a simple post request can get the data:

[image]

So all you need is to mimic that request:

```
import requests

# you can change there fields to get different results
data = {"selectFields":["Name","URL","Specialists"],"filters":{},"orderBy":{"Name":-1}}

post = "http://www.emoryhealthcare.org/service/findPhysician/api/locations/retrieve"
 #  post the data as json and create a dict from the returned json.
js = requests.post(post, json=data).json()
print(js[u'locations'][0][u'Specialists'])
```

Which if we run it gives you:

```
In [3]: import requests
...: 
...: data = {"selectFields":["Name","URL","Specialists"],"filters":{},"orderB
...: y":{"Name":-1}}
...: post =   "http://www.emoryhealthcare.org/service/findPhysician/api/locatio
...: ns/retrieve"
...: js = requests.post(post, json=data).json()
...: print(js[u'locations'][0][u'Specialists'])
...: 
[u'Gastroenterology', u'Internal Medicine']
```

There is a multitude of data in the json, pretty much anything you probably want is in there.